# PCB's with Connectors

Tags: pcb-design, connector

Are there any guidelines, standards or rules of thumb to follow when designing a PCB with connectors (USB, ethernet, etc.) that will need to fit into a case with a back panel? More specifically, how far should a connector be allowed to hang over the edge of the board?

Is it mostly just season to taste?

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: I can't see that it says anything about it. http://www.on-shore.com/sites/default/files/manuals/USB-B1HSXX.pdf

Comment: If those two large holes are off the board then you're doing it wrong. Otherwise, have fun.

Comment: Some USB connectors provide drawings to help determine the overhang beyond the edge of the board. For example [Molex 56579-0519](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0565790519_IO_CONNECTORS.xml). The second page shows a useful diagram. I believe Ethernet sockets have diagrams too. Parameters still available are the thickness of the case walls, distance of PCB from the case, and whether their are cutouts for plugs.

Comment: @gbulmer  +1.  I was going to make a similar post with a reference to a datasheet.  You might as well post this as an answer along with a snippet from the datasheet drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some USB connectors provide drawings to help determine the overhang beyond the edge of the board.

For example [Molex 56579-0519](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/565790519_sd.pdf). The second page shows a useful diagram:
[image]

This shows the distance between the plug and the end of the socket (1.5mm).

I believe Ethernet sockets have similar diagrams too.

Parameters still available are the thickness of the case walls, distance of PCB from the case, and whether their are cutouts for plugs.

I don't think there are general rules, but as shown by this example, manufacturers datasheet diagrams usually show clearance dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have a general rule for this.

How far a connector extends beyond the edge of the PC board depends on:

1. How the board sits in the case - how close is the board to the side of the case?
2. How thick is the side of the case?
3. how far into the side does the connector have to go for the mating cable connector to fit?
4. various other factors I can't think of at the moment...

Comment: Yeah number 4 is what scares me!

Comment: How much shearing force is expected. You may want to use the case to help hold the connector in place.